# loading in scripts with wp_enqueue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, loading

```
<?php

//Load Javascript


function my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('fancyfields', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancyfields-1.2.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('headmap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/headmap.js', array('markerclusterer'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('infobox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infobox.js', array('markerclusterer'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('gmaps_google', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", false, null, true);
    wp_register_script('markerclusterer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/markclusterer.js', array('gmaps_google'), null, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('fancyfields');
    wp_enqueue_script('headmap');
    wp_enqueue_script('infobox');
    wp_enqueue_script('gmaps_google');
    wp_enqueue_script('markerclusterer');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
?>
```

am i missing something here?

Why is this not working. I have placed the above code into the childs function.php file, but they scripts are not loading on the pages I need.

Can someone see a serious flaw here?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You said this is in a child theme so I'm presuming that's where the files are located as well.

`get_template_directory_uri()` will return the parent theme. The files can't be found there so they aren't loaded.

Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.

E.g.

```
wp_register_script('fancyfields', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/fancyfields-1.2.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

Comment: actually the scripts are loading except jquery! so annoying. I have tried to deregister it and use google librarys - but it just wont load.

Comment: There are a number of reasons this could be happening. I'd suggest you avoid trying to deregister it and see if it loads. Be aware that it will load in the head of your site. Open up your parent theme's header.php (or child theme if you're overriding) and make sure `wp_head();` is present

Comment: ya it is, but any of the scripts above with array("jquery") do not load... so I know it is not loading, I am just trying to figure out why...

Comment: Perform this quick test. Give your action a low priority. `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts', 9999);` Let me know the result.

Comment: I added the 9999, but I am not sure what this should be doing? where can I give you the result? what results? Nothing changed, the scripts reliant on jquery still fail to load.

Comment: My jsfiddle works with all the scripts, but when it was time to transfer them to my wordpress site, it is messing up. on my fiddle jquery 1.9.1 is loaded with 
no wrap - <in head>